# How to disable the sound when logging off / locking / switching users?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, logoff

I need to disable the sound that gets emitted on Windows 7 when a user logs off. I presume it should be as easy as finding the sound file that gets played and renaming it while logged in with administrator privileges.

Can someone please tell me how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I need to disable the sound that gets emitted on Windows 7 when a user logs off

The default sound filename for Windows Logoff is `C:\Windows\Media\Windows Logoff Sound.wav`

To disable the Windows Logoff Sound:

1. "Start" > "Control Panel" > "Sound"
2. Select "Sounds" tab
3. Scroll the "Program Events" list and select "Windows Logoff"
4. Change "Sounds" to "(None)" and press "OK"

   [image]

Note:

- This is a per user configuration. To change the sound for all users replace `C:\Windows\Media\Windows Logoff Sound.wav` with a silent `.wav` file with the same name.

Comment: A quick alternative way(at least on a Windows 7) to open the "Sound" Windows is by right clicking the desktop > Personalize > Sounds.